# js recognize if c# (asp.net) method is done

Tags: asp.net, loader

I would like to know if is there any way to recognize when c# (asp.net) method is finished in JS?

For Example:
1) User click on the Button and I show him the loader a the method starts
2) when the method is done I would like to recognize it, because I would like to hide the loader and after it I would like Response the file to the browser.

Is there any way? thanks

Comment: How do you "start the method"?

Comment: normally, the button is normally <asp:Button .....> - by  OnClick

Answer (score 0):

You can define the webmethod that runs the operation in a page, for example Operations.aspx:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string RunOperation(int someParameter)
{
..
}
```

and use jQuery and a ajax call

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
        $('#progressbar').show();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'Operations.aspx/RunOperation',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: { someParameter: $("#txt1").val() },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                $('#progressbar').hide();
            },
            error: function(data) {
                $('#progressbar').hide();
                alert('.......');
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

this script

- intercepts the clic of a button with id "btnSubmit"
- show a progressbar (for example a div centered on screen)
- call the method RunOperation in the page Operations.aspx passing a parameter with value param (for example the content of a text field with id txt1)
- when the call finishes, hide the progress bar

I don't know the context of your application but this should be a good start point.

Cheers.

Mario.